# Unable to retrieve firebase database to an android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

### Problem in retrieving firebase database to an android app.

[Here is the image of firebase realtime database updating from from raspberry pi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiAHP.png)

---

### error: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String

Below is my **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView tempvalue;
private TextView humidvalue;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private DatabaseReference mRootReference  = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
private DatabaseReference mChildReference = mRootReference.child("user").child("");
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tempvalue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tempvalue);
    humidvalue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.humidvalue);
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
     mChildReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String Temperature = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            String Humidity = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            tempvalue.setText(Temperature);
            humidvalue.setText(Humidity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}}
```

---

[output error while i'm running it into my phone(usb-debugging)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEnJf.png)
*

Answer (score 0):

Its because you listen to null.

your database reference is like this:

```
   mChildReference= mRootReference.child("user").child("");
```

this part

```
   .child("");
```

is listening to a null node. Hence your error

You must add the exact path that you are trying to read.

**EDIT**

okay use this as the ref:

```
     mChildReference= mRootReference.child("user");
```

and listen to the values like this:

```
     mChildReference.addValueEvent(new Value......{

       onDataChange(DataSnapshot datasnapshot){

       String temprature= datasnapshot.child("Temprature").getValue().toString();

       String humidity= datasnapshot.child("Humidity").getValue().toString();



        }




     })
```

Comment: That is my exact issue thanks for that but how do I select the child of arbitrary hashvalues..please have a look at the database image of mine

Comment: @Ashu add your database pic under your code for others to see, avoid links.

Comment: @Ashu add it in your question, press Edit button under your question and then click the image button to add the image to your question. Do it.

Comment: i don't have sufficient  reputions to do so

Comment: @Ashu make sure .("Temprature") and .("Humidity") are spelled the same in your database

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userRef = rootRef.child("user");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String humidity = ds.child("Humidity").getValue(String.class);
            String temperature = ds.child("Temperature").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", humidity + " / " + temperature);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

It will print the humidity and temperature of all objects.

If you want to display the value of a single object, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userRef = rootRef.child("user").child("-L6wEaOp58bSnCGUTSMs");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String humidity = dataSnapshot.child("Humidity").getValue(String.class);
        String temperature = dataSnapshot.child("Temperature").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", humidity + " / " + temperature);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Alex mamo......but the app updates from the DB only if II restart it(i mean exiting and starting the app)

Comment: like it is not dyamically updating the childs.

Comment: This sounds to be another problem. Does this error still appear? "error: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String"?